# Can I delete old Messages threads automatically?

Tags: messages

I would like to remove old Messages threads. Is there any way to do this, manually or automatically, other than deleting them one-by-one?

Is there an API for deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

It's in Messages Prefs, though it doesn't have much in the way of granularity…

[image]

<sup>Drop menu artificially floated away for clarity.</sup>

Comment: Nice, but that didn't delete on all of my devices. Does it ever delete them from the server?